# display time on iphone, is there a better way than Timer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer

i'm looking at displaying the current time in HH:mm format, and ive been checking around for the best way to do this.

Most examples have a Timer being executed every second, updating a textlabel for example.

Now, i'm imagining that this might drain a bit of battery if it's to run every second, which seems like overkill if all i'm displaying is hours and minutes. On the other hand, i don't want the minute-switch to happen 30 seconds later than the actual minute switch...

Is there some way to get a call when the phone clock changes minute or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the battery. NSTimer exists for this purpose. Use it!

Comment: Heh ok :) Thats what i did... ofcourse making sure that it only ticks when the view is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

1. Calculate the time interval between now and the next minute start
2. schedule a one off NSTimer to fire after that time interval
3. update the display when it fires
4. Go back to step 1.

Comment: Any advantage here to doing 1 off's rather than repeats?

Comment: @Luke: The timer only has to fire when you really need to do work and the timer will fire close to the minute meaning the display will change at the right time and not possibly 30 seconds late.

Comment: I don't understand what your saying, so your saying that repeating a timer can cause a late fire?

Comment: I'm saying that firing a timer every minute does not necessarily mean that it will fire exactly on the minute.  If you start the timer at 12:00:30, it will fire 30 seconds after every minute.